# ¿Por qué obtengo: Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de matrices en C++, utilizando Sublime Text. El ejercicio consta de pedir el numero de filas y columnas de una matriz en particular, e imprimir la diagonal principal de la matriz.
Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numeros[100000][100000], filas, columnas;

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>numeros[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Matriz completa: ";
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
            cout << numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Diagonal principal: ";
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
            if(i==j) {
                cout << numeros[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pero, al ejecutar el codigo, me da este error:

```
$ ./result
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Por lo que lei, es porque hay un problema relacionado a memoria, pero no encuentro cual es el problema. Como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Ese error se debe a intentar acceder a una posición de memoria que no deberías. Tiene sentido que suceda si no inicializaste las variables `filas` y `columnas` ya que contienen basura. Igual falta información. ¿Podrías debugear el código y ver dónde ocurre el error?

Comment: No crees que `10,000,000,000` de números no serán demasiados? Eso son 40GB de memoria que tu programa va a necesitar. Dudo que tengas 40GB de memoria RAM en tu pc. Además de que el tamaño del stack es limitado a unos cuantos megabytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí tienes tu problema:

```
int numeros[100000][100000];
```

Este array ocupa:

```
sizeof(int)*100000*100000 bytes = 40.000.000.000 bytes ~ 40GB
```

Esto es un problema por dos razones:

1. Es bastante probable que tu equipo no tenga 40GB de memoria RAM. Lo mismo puede conseguirlo tirando de memoria virtual... pero aún así hay muchos equipos que no tienen tantos recursos. Si tu equipo no tiene memoria suficiente para tu programa, tu programa morirá
2. Estás intentando almacenar el array en la pila del programa, una región de memoria bastante limitada. Su tamaño se suele medir en KB o, siendo bastante generosos, en MB, pero nunca jamás en GB. Nuevamente, si la pila se desborda, tu programa morirá.

Luego tienes otros problemas, como que las variables `filas` y `columnas` no están inicializadas, luego tendrán valores basura (o aleatorios, como prefieras denominarlos) que no van a coincidir con los que tu esperas.

Lo primero que deberías hacer es preguntar al usuario por el tamaño de la matriz:

```
int filas, columnas;
std::cout << "Dimensiones de la matriz\n"
          << "Filas: ";
std::cin >> filas;

std::cout << "Columnas: ";
std::cin >> columnas;
```

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes reservar exactamente la cantidad de memoria que necesitas. Aquí usamos `new`, que hará uso de la memoria dinámica, no de la pila. Aquí tendremos a nuestra disposición toda la RAM de nuestro equipo:

```
int ** numeros = new int*[filas];
for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    numeros[i] = new int[columnas];
```

Y ya estaría. Ahora, salvo que el usuario sea un sádico y disfrute rellenando una matriz de 100kx100k, tu programa no debería tener problemas de memoria.

Nota final: No olvides liberar con `delete[]` la memoria que has reservado con `new[]`